# Trigger Knockout-Event from outside

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following Select-Element in an html-form:

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: candidateList, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'title', optionsAfterRender: setOptionTitle, selectedOptions: selectedCandidates, optionsAfterRender: setOptionTitle, event: { dblclick: addSelectedCandidate, change: candidateChanged }, enable: enabled()">
<option title="first" value="1">first</option>
<option title="second" value="2">second</option>
<option title="third" value="3">third</option>
</select>
```

Now I select multiple Elements of that Select using jQuery-Methods setting the "Option SELECTED" - value.

As you can see, that select has a data-binding on it, which is from knockout. That knockout-code is in another JavaScript-File provided by someone else. We cannot really change content there. And our code is NOT knockout-, but simple jQuery-Code.

Now my problem is, that there are validations on that select. When I click onto an element manually, this enables another Button etc.

But when I try to do this by code, nothing happens. I tried inserting the "selected", `$(option).trigger('click')`, `$(option).click()`, `$(option).trigger('change')` and `$(option).change()`;

Is there any way to force knockout to "recognize" the stuff we change programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val` and then `trigger('change')` and it'll work. Here's a demo:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  candidateList: [{ id: 1, title: "first" }, { id: 2, title: "second" }, { id: 3, title: "third" }],
  setOptionTitle: function() { },
  selectedCandidates: ko.observableArray(),
  addSelectedCandidate: function() { },
  candidateChanged: function() { },
  enabled: ko.observable(true)
});

function getRandomVal() { return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1)) + 1).toString(); }

window.setInterval(function() {
  var vals = [];
  if (Math.random() > 0.75) { vals.push(getRandomVal()); }
  if (Math.random() > 0.75) { vals.push(getRandomVal()); }
  if (Math.random() > 0.75) { vals.push(getRandomVal()); }
  $("select").val(vals).trigger("change");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: candidateList, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'title', optionsAfterRender: setOptionTitle, selectedOptions: selectedCandidates, optionsAfterRender: setOptionTitle, event: { dblclick: addSelectedCandidate, change: candidateChanged }, enable: enabled()">
<option title="first" value="1">first</option>
<option title="second" value="2">second</option>
<option title="third" value="3">third</option>
</select>

<hr>
Selected candidates: <code data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedCandidates, null, 2)"></code>
```

PS. You have mostly a political problem probably, if you cannot change the code where your changes probably actually *should* go. Mixing jQuery and KO like this will hurt you in the short run, and it will hurt you *badly* in the long run.

PPS. There's a few weird things (without context at least) in that KO code as posted. First, it has `option`s in it, but those should be *generated*. Second, the `change` event is listened to, but typically a subscription or writeable computed would be a better choice. Third, the `optionsAfterRender` is declared twice. Lastly, the `enabled` value is executed, which is superfluous if it would be an observable.

Comment: Thanks. This is a Multi-Select, How do I set the value? Just as an array val(["1","2","3"])?