# Knockout js default click list element on page load binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to trigger click `li` event using knockout js on page load.

I have tried `click: function(){ $(this)[0].click(); }`. But its not working. anyone help me to achieve this.

```
<li data-bind="css: { active: isActive },click: function(){ $(this)[0].click(); }" class="active">
    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="active-border" aria-expanded="true">
        <span>One</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I want to use only knockout js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5658925/3193524 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840257/trigger-knockout-event-from-outside might help

Comment: @FSDford It doesn't help me to solve this.

Comment: why not use jquery when you use jquery in knockout anyway btw. it should be `$(this).click(); ` what do you want to achieve? what function is ran when clicking li ?

Comment: @johnSmith when clicking `li` the active tab should load instead of default selected tab. If I use jquery script trigger after some time. I want to do a quick action that's why playing around with knockout

Comment: the runtime order is totally up to you, you could even run jquery scripts before applying the viewmodel, but you would not want that. Just take a look at the `default selected tab` and cut the code `probably just adding class active` to your desired tab

Comment: @johnSmith not understand thank you