# Select changed by javascript fails to trigger change event

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, cefsharp

The setup I have is a cefsharp (Chromium) browser in a VB.net application, but I am new to javascript which is being used to change dropdowns displayed in the embedded browser. I have a page on which I need to programmatically change two dropdowns, one to select a date of a meeting and the other to select which fund the meetings are about. These are defined in the html as

```
<select id="ddl-meetings" tabindex="0" data-bind="options: Meetings,
        optionsText: 'Value',
        optionsValue : 'Key',
        value: SelectedMeeting">
        <option value="9001">June 18 2020 - Other </option><option value="9002">June 18 2020 - Annual </option></select>
```

```
<select id="ddl-fund" aria-label="Funds" tabindex="0" data-bind="options: Funds, 
        optionsText: 'Value', 
        optionsValue: 'Key', 
        value: SelectedFund, 
        event:{ change: onSelectedFund}">
        <option value="2001">Fund A</option><option value="2002">Fund B</option><option value="2003">Fund C</option></select>
```

Part of the system appears to be Knockout.js, but I have no access to the server side and no-one who worked on it remains.

If I manually change the meetings dropdown (ddl-meetings) a webcall is being made and the meetings part of the page updates to show the relevant list of meetings for that date (and the selected fund).
Again if I manually change the funds dropdown (ddl-fund) there is a webcall and the meetings part of the page changes to show those meetings regarding the funds on the date selected.
I can programmatically alter the meetings date dropdown using the javascript, in this case selecting “June 18 2020 – Annual” and the section of the page updates as expected.

```
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.querySelector('#ddl-meetings').value='9002';")
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('#ddl-meetings').trigger('change');")
```

The issue is that doing the same from the second drop down (funds) fails to update the section of the page, the dropdown changes to show the selected fund (in this case Fund C), but no other activity occurs.

```
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.querySelector('#ddl-fund').value='2003';")
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('#ddl-fund').trigger('change');")
```

This looks like the onSelectedFund event is not firing and I’ve not been able to find a way to get it to do so, for example these attempts fail

```
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync ("$('#ddl-fund').val("2003").trigger("onSelectedFund");")
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync ("document.getElementById('ddl-fund').dispatchEvent(change);")
```

I have also tried giving focus, click events and so on. Nothing seems to result in the same behaviour that occurs when the funds dropdown is manually changed and while I’ve found a few similar javascript issues discussed online the solutions put forward fail on the funds dropdown.

I would really like to know why this doesn’t work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A quick search yields https://stackoverflow.com/a/35841591/4583726 it's been years since I used knockoutjs so don't remember the specifics. I'd suggest adding the knockout.js tag. From a CefSharp point of view I'd point out you can open DevTools and get a better understanding of what's going on https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: If you're lucky, this might work: `ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('ddl-fund')).onSelectedFund('2003', null)`. It will only run if (a) `ko` is exposed in `window`, and (b) the `onSelectedFund` method does not rely on the actual change event that it is supposed to get as a second parameter.

Comment: user3297291’s comment on using `ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('ddl-fund')).onSelectedFund('2003', null)` gets me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalEvent' of null` it seems the onSelectedFund is dependent on it.
`e._viewModel.onSelectedFund = function(n, t) {
                    t.originalEvent && e.loadAgendaByFund()
                }` Still working on it.